# Find if Entered Password is valid or not?

Tags: java

This is an interview question. I think the code below, works a bit and has some errors. The problem is as follows -

In 1-9 keypad one key is not working. If some one enters a password then not working key will not be entered. You have given expected password and entered password. Check that entered password is valid or not 
Ex: entered 164, expected 18684 (you need to take care as when u enter 18684 and 164 only both will be taken as 164 input)

The code which does above is below.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(IsAMatch("164","18684"));  
    } 
    static boolean IsAMatch(String actual, String expected)
    {
        char faultyKey = '\0';
        int i = 0, j = 0;
        for(; i < expected.length() && j < actual.length(); ++i)
        {
            if(actual.charAt(j) != expected.charAt(i))
            {
                if('\0' != faultyKey){
                    if(faultyKey != expected.charAt(i))
                        return false;
                }
                else{
                    faultyKey = expected.charAt(i);
                }
            }
            else{
                ++j;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("FaultyKey= "+faultyKey);
        return (i == expected.length() - 1 && j == actual.length() - 1)? true : false;
    }
```

It is detecting the faulty key correctly (Ex here it is 8), but giving wrong output (As False) Even though the test case used above should give true. 
Any suggestions to fix this? If any better method/ideas are most appreciated.

Comment: FYI - At all Others who have suggested to remove -1 from the return statement. It gives me wrong answer for the IsAMatch("164","1868488")

Comment: Seemingly there was more then one problem with the code then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
static boolean IsAMatch(String actual, String expected) {
        char faultyKey = '\0';
        int i = 0, j = 0;
        for (; i < expected.length(); ++i) {
            if (j >= actual.length() || actual.charAt(j) != expected.charAt(i)) {
                if ('\0' != faultyKey) {
                    if (faultyKey != expected.charAt(i)) {
                        return false;
                    }
                } else {
                    faultyKey = expected.charAt(i);
                }
            } else {
                ++j;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("FaultyKey= " + faultyKey);
        return (i == expected.length() && j == actual.length()) ? true : false;
    }
```

Consider the following condition

```
System.out.println(IsAMatch("164", "186848"));
```

Your logic will not work, because before i meets the length j would meet the actual length.
you dont need to have condition `j < actual.length` in for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Change the return statement to:

```
return (i == expected.length() && j == actual.length())? true : false;
```

The bug is that i and j are both increased first and then checked if they meet the loop condition. Obviously both i and j fail to meet the condition as the control flow breaks out from the loop. Therefore, i and j are exactly equal to  expected and actual length respectively.

Moreover, the expression in your return statement is gratuitous. You could just return true at that point of the program as it is a tautology at that stage. I.e. there is no way that you can be at that point in your code and your expression evaluates to false.

Answer (score 0):

Your return statement should be :

```
return (i == expected.length()  && j == actual.length()) ? true : false;
```

or, simpler :

```
return (i == expected.length()  && j == actual.length());
```

because i and j reach the length of the strings when the loop ends.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with these two statements:

```
i == expected.length() - 1
j == actual.length() - 1
```

Remove the - 1 by each of them and it should work fine.